# How to extract multiple substrings from an expression using VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, string, vba

I have an `expression` input from a user which can be like

```
{{heading1} + {{heading2} * {heading3}}}
```

Each heading is included in braces `{}` when written in expression.

I want to extract "heading1" "heading2" and "heading3" in a `String` `Array` separately using an Excel macros. Please help me with the code.

Comment: I couldn't try anything since I am new to VBA. Only C and Java are my forte.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions.
[Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions) are used for Pattern Matching.  To use in Excel follow these steps.

**Step 1**: Add VBA reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"

- Select "Developer" tab ([I don't have this tab what do I do?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx))
- Select "Visual Basic" icon from 'Code' ribbon section
- In "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications" window select "Tools" from the top menu.
- Select "References"
- Check the box next to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" to include in your workbook.
- Click "OK"

#### Example

```
Private Sub regEx()

    Dim UserInput As String
    UserInput = "{{heading1} + {{heading2} * {heading3}}}"

    Dim Pattern As String
    Pattern = "\{([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\}"

    Dim regEx As New RegExp

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = Pattern
    End With

    Dim Matches
    Set Matches = regEx.Execute(UserInput)

    For Each Match In Matches
        Debug.Print "Match found at position " & Match.FirstIndex
        Debug.Print "Match Value is '" & Match.Value & "'"
        Debug.Print ""
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Cool.. Its been really helpful. I have one more question if we can replace heading1, heading2, heading3 and so on in the expression with #1, #2, ...and so on, with consecutive numbers. Can you help me out which function to use for the above?

Comment: You can adjust the pattern in between the brackets `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. At the moment it allows any lower case and upper case letters as well as numbers. If you need other characters you have to modify that pattern. E.g. to allow `#` change it to `[a-zA-Z0-9#]`. But be careful some special characters have to be escaped with a backslash as they are used as operators in regular expressions.